# How to create an animation( un tying a bow) on iphone or android?

Tags: android, iphone, animation

I want to create an animation for an app for both iphone and android, that will display a ribbon in a bow. Then when the ribbon is pulled(touched) the application opens.

How would i go about creating this for either or both the iphone or the android platform

Regards

Comment: Your best choice for such a complex animation would most likely be to have a pre-made video/image sequence, and then you advance the frames as the user pulls the ribbon (or rewind if he lets go).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create this animation in Flash and export movie as image frames.. and then use a UIImageView

```
// create the view that will execute our animation
     UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

     // load all the frames of our animation
     campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire01.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire02.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire03.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire04.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire05.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire06.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire07.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire08.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire09.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire10.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire11.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire12.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire13.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire14.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire15.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire16.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire17.jpg"], nil];

     // all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
     campFireView.animationDuration = 1.75;
     // repeat the annimation forever
     campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
     // start animating
     [campFireView startAnimating];
     // add the animation view to the main window
     [self.view addSubview:campFireView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the animation by using static images as per this page:
http://android-support-akkilis.blogspot.com/2011/12/animation-drawbles-in-android.html 
This shows how to make a naimation effect using the static images by providing the time per frame.
Else have a tutorial video or something like this.